# Alternative Formulation of Russell's Paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory, paradoxes

Someone recently told me about a very interesting variant of Russell's Paradox they once saw that goes like this:
$$S=\{x : \neg \exists y [ x \in y \ \& \ y \in x]\}.$$
Does anyone have any references that explain or mention this variant of Russell's Paradox, or that could perhaps explain this variant of the paradox themselves?

Comment: If I recall correctly, we gave it as a homework exercise four years ago on the first week of intro to set theory.

Comment: Well, at least I know it probably exists. If you know how to explain that version of the paradox, please do!

Comment: Assuming you want to prove $$\neg\exists S: \forall x:[x\in S \iff \neg\exists y:[x\in y \land y\in x]]$$here is my formal proof in my DC Proof 2.0 format: http://www.dcproof.com/RussellsParadoxAlternativeVersion.html

Comment: Reformatted my proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $S$ is a set. Now we ask, is there some $x\in S$ such that $S\in x$?

If the answer is positive, then $x\in S$ and $S\in x$, and therefore $x\notin S$, by the very definition of $S$. Therefore the answer must be negative, but then $S\in S$, so by taking $x=S$ we get $S\in S$ and $S\in S$.

In either case, we run into a contradiction, and therefore $S$ is not a set.